# Client not updating realtime with Socket.io and Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets

Why isn't my client side updating automatically using socket.io and node.js?

My backend accepts JSON POST requests from PHP, then it emits the data to all connected devices.

My backend code

```
app.post('/', function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.body);
    subdata = req.body;
    res.send('ok');
});

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.broadcast.emit('info', subdata);
});
```

Client side

```
<script>
    var socket = io.connect('http://127.0.0.1:3000/');
    socket.on('info', function (data) {
      console.log(data);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: What's `subdata`? Don't work with global variables. Global variables in asynchronous JavaScript code are a bug in almost every case.

Comment: subdata holds json sent by PHP in `req.body`

Comment: That's not what I meant. `subdata` *does not exist* in the `io.sockets.on('connection')` callback. It's a global variable the way you use it, and you *cannot use global variables in asynchronous code*.

Comment: how can I fix this? I am new to nodejs

Comment: it's pointless to do something without knowing the basic

Answer (score 0):

That's because you only ever emit once when a new socket.io connection is made. If the `app.post` callback is called again, there's nothing to emit another message from `socket.io`.

You want to emit from within your `app.post` callback, and stop using global variables.

Comment: can you site snippets?